# Why am I getting a syntax error when running in terminal?

Tags: python

I'm getting a syntax error: invalid syntax on this. I'm using python 2.7.13 and running it on terminal on my mac. I run it without the - print 'blastoff' - statement and it counts down correctly, but when I include the print statement it gives me a syntax error. Obviously I'm new to this but I am following the guide that I'm studying and writing it exactly in terminal.

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print n
    n = n - 1
print 'blastoff'
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error you are getting? I copied and ran your code just fine with no errors.

Comment: What is the *exact* syntax error? I suspect you are using Python 3, or you are using `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: Your example is working fine with python-2.7, as the other suggested which is the syntax error and can you get the python version from terminal?

Comment: Thank you for replying. The exact python version I am using is: Python 2.7.13. And I believe the exact syntax error is: invalid syntax, and it references line 4